# Default property value for image

Tags: next.js, react-typescript

I was wondering if there is a way I can simplify this following line of code WITHOUT destructing the properties parameter. I'm trying to set favicon.ico as the default image if properties.user_image is not provided

"src={properties.user_image ? properties.user_image : "favicon.ico"}"

````
'"use client";

import { Card, Image, Button } from "@/components/bootstrap";
import { HiCog } from "react-icons/hi";

interface UserCardProps {
  user_name: string;
  user_specialty: string;
  user_image?: string;
  user_posts: string;
  user_location: string;
  user_current: boolean;
}

export default function UserCard(properties: UserCardProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Card className="mb-3 shadow flex-row">
        <Card.Body>
          <Image
            className="image-user-card"
            src={properties.user_image ? properties.user_image : "favicon.ico"}
            roundedCircle
            alt="user card"
          />

          <Card.Title>{properties.user_name}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
            {properties.user_specialty}
          </Card.Subtitle>
          <p className="mb-4 text-muted text-small-custom">
            {properties.user_location}
          </p>
          <Card.Text className="text-muted text-small-custom">
            {"Posts: " + properties.user_posts}
          </Card.Text>
          <Card.Link href="#">Card Link 1</Card.Link>
          <Card.Link href="#">Card Link 2</Card.Link>
        </Card.Body>

        <div>
          {properties.user_current && (
            <Button className="button-corner-custom" href="/Profile">
              <HiCog size={20}></HiCog>
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) returns the LHS if it is *not* `undefined` or `null` and the RHS otherwise.

```
properties.user_image ?? "favicon.ico"
```